# GoDaddy Filename Extension Rewrite on Subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

GoDaddy user here. I have my .htaccess file which allows the php extension to be ignored. I believe it is written correctly:

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

However, on the server, my root directory isn't '/' on this specific site because this is a subdomain, it's 'mysite/public/' so when I try and access my site, I get a 404, because it says it's trying to access

```
'mysite/public/mysite/public/mywebpage.php'
```

Obviously it's trying to access the entire root directory **on top of** the root directory, which I'm trying not to have happen. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use appropriate `RewriteBase`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't think rewrite base is the problem, because I want the base to be '/' considering it's appending it. Using your .htaccess file but changing /public/ back to '/' I'm getting the correct directory, but on the last line, $1 is being evaluated to 'p' instead of the filename. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I missed `$` in last line. See updated answer.

Comment: Editing your answer to change back RewriteBase to '/' because that worked for me. I just had to move .htaccess into my root directory of the subdomain which was mysite/public, and then everything worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for making that edit that I forgot. Great to know it worked out.